# How to handle account balances?

Tags: transaction-fees, exchanges, buy-bitcoins, balance

My goal is to manage the investments of a huge group of people. Let's say that each month each one puts in a different amount of dollars (it may even be $1) and I need to send to his wallet that amount in bitcoin. If I'll send to each person his own share of bitcoin, **I'll lose a lot of money because of fees**, there are a lot of micro transactions.

[image: diagram]

Is there any suggestions how I can manage this the best way?

When you come to think about it, any chance it's similar to how stock exchanges dealing with managing accounts balances? no way they are paying the bitcoin transfer fee on each transaction inside the exchange. it's not sustainable.

1. I thought about maybe purchasing the bitcoin in bulk, and save it, and to write each account balance in my own ledger, that way each user doesn't really have a wallet.

   - pros: no transactions fees.
   - cons: user doesn't really have a wallet, I'm fully in charge of his money in case his getting hacked.

   How does the exchanges handle keeping all that crypto assets??
2. I thought about creating each user a wallet, but it means I can't support small investments.

I'd love some help here.

Comment: If the investors invest dollars, why don't you return dollars?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I'd like to show them, on each investment they've done, how much btc it got them, and to attach it to their wallet. so if they want to quit,  it'll let them do anything they want with it. (Although I can't seem to find a solution which involves each investor having his own wallet, because of the fees)